# Cannot download documents since updated to 6.0.1

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, mac, tor-button

Since I updated to 6.0.1 I cannot download any document from Tor to my desktop. I use the download button at the upper right corner (five icons: full screen-print-download-other-doublearrow) that appear when a pdf document is shown up, but nothing happens.
I have to open another browser, copy the url and download from it. Haven't changed parameters from default.
I run OSX 10.7.5 on an end 2006 iMac.

Comment: Can you tell on which sites this happens?

Comment: Everyone since pdfwiewer activates. At that time I was trying tomdownload laws from different official sites http://www.boe.es/ or http://www.xunta.gal/diario-oficial-galicia/mostrarContenido.do?method=detalleHome&fecha=20160617&ruta=%2Fsrv%2Fwww%2Fdoga%2FPublicados%2F2016%2F20160617%2FIndice115_gl.html

Comment: See my updated answer, this bug has been fixed in 6.0.2

Comment: Fine. Just updated to 6.0.2 and it does work. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It seems ticket [#15899](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/15899) had similar issues with the pdf.js download button, I don't see any errors in the console. It may be worth re-opening this ticket. I see similarly no activity as a result on clicking the download button on pdf.js running on Tails 2.4.

As a work around `Right Click` -> `Save Page As` (do macs even do right clicks yet?) and `File` -> `Save Page As` should both still work.

**Update: This bug has been fixed under [#19401](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/19401) a patch is now applied in Tor Browser 6.0.2**

Comment: Thanks. I made several querys with no results. Yes, it seems that it may be the same thing, but ... 1) the solution it gives is a piece of code in ... what is that? php? that I will not dare trying to implement with the browser I ordinarily use. Unless someone insert that piece of code in the next update I won´t be able. 2) "Save Page as" using comands or ctrl+mouse (osx without mighty mouse) or right mouse button (with mighty mouse) just gives the first page and not the complete pdf document

Comment: Correction: Save page as, does download the complete document. That may be a solution. Thanks.